# Two single clicks to rename something in html?

Tags: angularjs, events, rename

In OS X, if I do a single click on a file or folder to highlight it, and then do another single click on the filename, the filename becomes an editable input box that I can change the filename in that box. Now I found `xeditable` http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#overview very useful. I'm wondering in html, or Angularjs, is there such two single click event? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by the following code:

```
app.controller('QueryItemCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.rename = function () {
        $scope.lastClickTime = $scope.lastClickTime || 0;
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var delta = now - $scope.lastClickTime;
        $scope.lastClickTime = now;
        if (delta > 500 && delta < 1000) {
            $scope.textBtnForm.$show();
        }
    };
})
```

In the html, `data-ng-click="rename()"`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its a ng-dblclick used the same as ng-click
here's and example:

```
<button ng-dblclick="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">
 Increment (on double click)
</button>
count: {{count}}
```

Comment: I think it's different from `dblclick`. `dblclick` actually will open that file, or folder. But two single clicks on the filename text will just trigger the input box. I already have `dblclick` bound to other action. Now I want to mimc the two single click behavior.